# Angular service test - TestBed ignores one of the mocks

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, testbed

I am having an issue with one of my spy objects - somehow TestBed seems to ignore it at all.

The spy for `StateService` works perfect, but the one for `RoutingService` keeps failing with:
`NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!` (the real `RoutingService` uses `Activated Route`).

Here's my service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})        
export class UserInteractionService {
  constructor(
   private stateService: StateService,
   private routingService: RoutingService
   ) {}
       
   handleUserInteraction(...) {
     // ...
     this.routingService.updateUrl();
   }
}
```

Here's service.spec.ts:

```
describe('UserInteractionService', () => {
  let service: UserInteractionService;

  const mockRoutingService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['updateUrl']);
  const mockStateService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['copyState']);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: StateService,
          useValue: mockStateService,
        },
        {
          provide: RoutingService,
          useValue: mockRoutingService, // not working??
        }
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(UserInteractionService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: try providing UserInteractionService in the TestBed providers

Comment: Or mock the ActivatedRoute...

Comment: @Yuriy it does not help unfortunately.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I want to use a mock so that I don't have to provide here 5 another dependencies for RoutingService. Anyway, even if I did it there's still a problem when I want to spy upon RoutingService methods, because the mock is simply not used.

Comment: Are you sure you are creating spy objects properly? Can you please try this:   const mockRoutingService = jasmine.createSpyObj('routingService', ['updateUrl']); for both of your mock services?

Comment: Can you check the imports ? Are you sure that the component and the test refer to the same "RoutingService" ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I feel so stupid right now! You're right, I was importing the wrong service... Thank you!

Comment: @Dandy Not stupid at all, quite frequent though. Rename the service if you can because it will happen again